# Docusign API: successful JSON submission of textTabs, but values don't appear in document

Tags: python, json, docusignapi

I am able to successfully submit a JSON containing `textTabs` and `fullName` tabs to the Docusign API (POST at [baseURL]`/envelopes`), calling a template, and I do receive the document to sign:

```
{ "accountId": "xxx",
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
  "emailBlurb": "Here's a document for you to sign",
  "templateId": "xxxx",
  "templateRoles": [
        {
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "name": "Test Recipient",
        "tabs": 
              { "textTabs":
                [{"tabLabel": "\\*Doc_Name",
                  "name": "Doc_Name",
                  "value": "Doc Value Goes Here",
                  "DocumentId": "1",
                  "PageNumber": "1"},

                  {"tabLabel": "\\*Doc_Phone",
                  "name": "Doc_Phone",
                  "value": "8675309",
                  "DocumentId": "1",
                  "PageNumber": "1"},


                  {"tabLabel": "\\*Doc_Fax",
                  "name": "Doc_Fax",
                  "value": "5551212",
                  "DocumentId": "1",
                  "PageNumber": "1"} ],

                "fullNametabs":
                  [ {"tabLabel": "FULLName",
                  "name": "FullName",
                  "value": "The Full Name Goes Here",
                  "DocumentId": "1",
                  "PageNumber": "1"}]

                          } 
                  ,

        "roleName": "parent_signer" }  ] }
```

My template has custom fields with the same Data Label within a document in that template:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuSEk.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVTgs.jpg

In the template's document, I've placed these fields in the body of the document:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9oAo.jpg

However, when the document arrives for signature, those fields are not pre-populated, as I would expect.  The document appears, buth as no pre-populated fields:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCc9o.jpg

**Is there a difference between envelope tabs, template tabs, and custom fields?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the recipient is not seeing the tabs in the Envelope is that `roleName` is case-sensitive and the case of `roleName` you're specifying in the JSON request (`parent_signer`) does not match the case of the recipient role name as it's specified in the Template (`Parent_signer`).

Additionally, there are several other improvements you can make to your JSON request:

- You don't need to specify `accountId` -- it's already specified in the request URI so including it in the body of the request is redundant and unnecessary.
- You don't need to specify `name` or `documentId` and `pageNumber` for each tab -- since the Template contains the tabs already, DocuSign already knows where they should appear within the document(s).
- You don't need to specify the Full Name tab in the request body -- DocuSign will automatically populate a Full Name tab with the name of the recipient (you actually can't specify a value for this type of tab, since DocuSign always sets the tab value automatically using the signer's name).

Here's your JSON request again, with these changes applied:

```
{ 
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
  "emailBlurb": "Here's a document for you to sign",
  "templateId": "xxxx",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "name": "Test Recipient",
      "tabs": 
        { 
          "textTabs": [
              {
                "tabLabel": "\\*Doc_Name",
                "value": "Doc Value Goes Here"
              },
              {
                "tabLabel": "\\*Doc_Phone",
                "value": "8675309"
              },
              {
                "tabLabel": "\\*Doc_Fax",
                "value": "5551212"
              }
          ]
        },
        "roleName": "Parent_signer" 
    }  
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Happy I could help!